# Slow Loading Accordion Issue

Tags: javascript

I have an Accordion with about 32 pieces of data attached to it inline.  For some reason when the Page first loads, the Accordion starts out open with all of the Answers exposed, for about 3 seconds, then they all close.

http://www.davincispainting.com/glossary.aspx

I know this begs for a Database solution but that's for a later Phase.

The issue happens whether there are 10 Questions/Answers or 32 Questions/Answers.

I can provide the JSFiddle for this, but obviously not with all of the Data that's causing the slow response.

I initially thought that I could break this out to several Accordions, but then when I only have 10 Questions/Answers the issue still occurs

Is this issue inherent with the Accordion?  Or is there a way I can set this for when the Page Loads to be sure not to expose Answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following into your CSS:

`.answer{ display: none; }`

Comment: @Prisoner That has to be a record, less than 3 minutes!

Comment: @Paul, it is best if you post it as a separate issue and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Prisoner I got it, it was the height w/in .answer

Comment: @Paul, I looked at the source and it you're setting the height in StyleSheet1.css under `dd`. You should probably just remove that one instead of having a miss-mash of CSS.

Comment: @Paul, I also took a look at your JS, you should look at jQuerys SlideDown/SlideUp as your current solution is very messy (saving the height, then checking it when animating the box).

Comment: @Prisoner its not even JQuery.  I got that from someone because this one prevents Jitter.

Comment: @Prisoner I got rid of the Height attribute for both .answer and dd, which enables the Height of that Answer Box to be as High as needed, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: none;` inline to each of the answer main divs. They have to be inline because most modules like that work inline.